# Aiogram can`t create InputMediaPhoto objects | 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, aiogram

**I have the following code for a callback query handler in my telegram bot:**

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.startswith('adm_additional_photos '))
async def adm_additional_photos(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.message.delete()
    model_id = callback_query.data.split(' ')[1]
    model = db.get_model(model_id)
    photos_list = model[9].replace('{', '').replace('}', '')
    if ',' in photos_list:
        photos_list = photos_list.split(',')
        print(photos_list, type(photos_list))
        media_group = []
        for photo in photos_list:
            print(photo)
            media_group.append(InputMediaPhoto(photo))
        await bot.send_media_group(callback_query.from_user.id, media=media_group)
```

**`photos_list` contains ID`s of photos I want to send to the user as a media group (as one message). But when the handler is activated, an error arises:**

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\escort_bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=TypeError("'NoneType' object is not iterable")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\escort_bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 286, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 180, in adm_additional_photos
    media_group.append(InputMediaPhoto(photo))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\input_media.py", line 200, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\input_media.py", line 49, in __init__
    super(InputMedia, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\base.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.props[key].set_value(self, value, parent=self)
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\fields.py", line 57, in set_value
    value = self.deserialize(value, parent)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\fields.py", line 141, in deserialize
    for item in value:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

**As you can see in my code, I have added printing out `photos_list` and it`s type and later each photo id from the list.
Below is the output (before the error):**

```
['AgACAgIAAxkBAAIBDmT6CRHnUWtprP-p5YbfwMj8u-fbAAKvzzEbSrjQSzY9H8ziYxRyAQADAgADeAADMAQ', 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIBEGT6CRXtkiaDKBJDhpLxQOBV8Bj_AAKuzzEbSrjQS3ASmmGWZs3eAQADAgADeAADMAQ'] <class 'list'>
AgACAgIAAxkBAAIBDmT6CRHnUWtprP-p5YbfwMj8u-fbAAKvzzEbSrjQSzY9H8ziYxRyAQADAgADeAADMAQ
```

**Everything seems right. Why the error might be arising? How do I correct my code so it doesn`t?**